# How to modify Pi Camera sensor size?

Tags: python, camera

I have an Arducam 5MP autofocus camera (OV5647), which I believe is almost identical to the Pi Camera V1, but with a motorized lens for focusing.

- https://www.arducam.com/product/raspberry-pi-camera-5mp-autofocus-motorized-focus-camera-b0176/

For a scientific use, I need to quickly obtain raw sensor data and process it. However, I don't need data from the entire sensor - rather, just the center 500x500 pixels. So, I figured that it would be great if I could configure the camera/sensor so that it only gathers data from that defined area, which should greatly speed up the raw data capturing and processing.

After some searching, I found that this is called "image windowing", and the window (active sensor size) is determined by registers on the camera (page 28 in link below):

- https://www.arducam.com/downloads/modules/RaspberryPi_camera/OV5647DS.pdf

However, it doesn't really make it clear how to modify the registers. I found some sparse resources online about reading and writing registers using I2C, but despite spending several hours on this, I can't figure how to do it. If anyone knows how to do this (maybe even with a completely different approach), it'd be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This seems like a question you should put to Arducam.

Comment: what is the exact problem you are trying to solve? ... the title says one thing and the description says something different

Comment: @joan I believe it belongs here because the Arducam is just a modified version of the original Pi Cam. The principles therefore should be very similar or the same. And because this camera is made specifically for Raspberry Pi, I believe it is on topic for this forum.

Comment: @jsotola I am wondering about how to modify sensor size (image windowing) for Raspberry Pi cameras. The description also says the same thing. I just added some extra information (regarding modifying registers) to demonstrate what steps I've taken to try to find an answer.

Comment: maybe I'm misreading your post ... to me it says that you do not know how to write to a register ... BTW, this site is not a forum